# How to import a file by its full path using C api?

Tags: python, python-c-api

```py
PyObject* PyImport_ImportModule( const char *name)
```

How to specify a full file path instead and a module name?

Like `PyImport_SomeFunction(const char *path_to_script, const char *name)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually, I ended up using the load_source from imp module:

```
s.sprintf( 
  "import imp\n" 
  "imp.load_source('%s', r'%s')", modname, script_path); 
PyRun_SimpleString(s.c_str());
```

I think it is the most feasible solution. Other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution for cases when all *.py file are in one directory:

```
PySys_SetPath("path/with/python/files");
PyObject *pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("filename_without_extension");
```

Comment: Warning, PySys_SetPath overwrites the path variable and your target python script may not be able to import its modules. you should prefer that solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137145/python-c-api-pyimport-importmodule-fail-when-the-file-has-an-import-statement

Comment: The comment here is more useful compare to the answer

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out, using the above solution by AlexP, you can't import any modules outside of the specified directory. However, instead of *setting* the path, you can *add* a path, which is to be searched for modules. This can be done by appending that path to [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path). Unfortunately the C API doesn't expose a function that is able to do that directly. Instead you can ask Python itself to do it, using

```
PyRun_SimpleString( "import sys\nsys.path.append(\"<insert folder path>\")\n" );
```

or any equivalent like:  **(warning: untested)**

```
PyObject* sys = PyImport_ImportModule( "sys" );
PyObject* sys_path = PyObject_GetAttrString( sys, "path" );
PyObject* folder_path = PyUnicode_FromString( "<insert folder path>" );
PyList_Append( sys_path, folder_path );
```

Now you can import any file `<insert folder path>/<file>.py` using the usual

```
PyObject* mymodule = PyImport_ImportModule( "<file>" );
```

To refer to the current directory, simply use `"."` as the folder path.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you a full answer, but I think I can give you a place to start. Python provides a built-in module called `imp` which provides access to import internals. It includes a function load_module() which lets you pass in a path. This is implemented in [Python/import.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r264/Python/import.c?view=markup); just search for `imp_load_module`.

Answer (score 2):

CPython will [not hesitate](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/import.c#L1706) to call through the `imp` module to perform import jobs, so there's no reason that you shouldn't do it yourself.

Here's one way to do it in C++, where `modulePath` and `moduleName` are separate variables because of laziness:

```cpp
PyObject* loadModule(const char* modulePath, const char* moduleName)
{
    auto modules = PyImport_GetModuleDict();
    auto impModule = PyDict_GetItemString(modules, "imp");
    if (impModule)
    {
        // GetItemString returns a borrowed reference, but ImportModule
        // returns a new reference, so INCREF here to even it out
        Py_INCREF(impModule);
    }
    else
    {
        impModule = PyImport_ImportModule("imp");
        if (!impModule)
        {
            // we've tried hard enough, bail out
            PyErr_Print();
            return nullptr;
        }
    }

    // The Python API asks for non-const char pointers :(
    char methodName[] = "load_source";
    char args[] = "ss";
    auto module = PyObject_CallMethod(impModule, methodName, args, moduleName, modulePath);

    Py_XDECREF(impModule);
    Py_XDECREF(modulePath);
    return module;
}
```

I wrote this based on [one of my projects' Python module loader](https://github.com/zneak/fcd/blob/826bfff26b4ed1ec8bf71a472efe931f4947ff13/fcd/python/pass_python.cpp#L144), which uses fancier refcount management, and I haven't tried this one, so use at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

I verified that the alternative of [stesim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2249821/stesim) works.

No matter which solution is used, it is important to mention that on windows it is important to have the full path with slashes instead of backslashes.

```
path = "C:\\path\\to\\module\\module.py" // wrong
path = "C:/path/to/module/module.py"     // correct
```

In some other questions and answers (like [Windows path in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)) it is stated, that the first variant should work too. I couldn't get it to work that way whatever method I tried.