# Python C api PyImport_importmodule fail when the file has an import statement

Tags: python, c++, python-import, python-c-api

I tried to use the Python C api to call a function from python in C++, the test was successful.

But if I intend to import a module already importing other module, the Pymodule_findmodule will return Null even though it's there and created a compiled file. Here is my code

```
Py_Initialize();
PySys_SetPath("C:/Users/Mik/Documents/GitHub/youtube-dl");      
PyObject * pythonFile = PyImport_ImportModule("test2");
```

Here is the python filed named test2.py at that directory with a file named test_dl.py and a class called TESTDL inside it

```
from test_dl import TESTDL 
def someFunction(someInput):
    return 12345
```

As soon as I added the import line my program doesnot recognize it as module anymore

Edit: turns out the test_dl has the first line as:

```
 from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

That's the reason I got this ImportError: No module named **future**

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you might have gotten an exception when trying to import `test_dl` or retrieve the `TESTDL` object from it.

Comment: What does `PyErr_Print()` print after your call to `PyImport_ImportModule("test2")`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function call to `PySys_SetPath()` completely overwrites the Python module path. The result is that your Python script `test_dl` cannot find Python system modules (in this case `__future__`) and throws an exception.

What you need to do is to *append* the directory of your module to the system path instead. To do that, first query the existing value of the system path, and then add your path to it:

```
PyObject *sys_path = PySys_GetObject("path");
PyList_Append(sys_path, PyString_FromString("C:/Users/Mik/Documents/GitHub/youtube-dl"));
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) Didn't realize I need the python lib as well

Comment: That only works with Python >=2.7. Here a more compatible version: append_path = PYTHON_PATH
    ":.";
    //append_path = '"'PYTHON_PATH:.";
    setenv("PYTHONPATH", append_path, 1); //Set PYTHONPATH TO working directory

Comment: PyString_FromString is not compliant with python >3.5, use PyUnicode_FromString instead