# C++ application crashes with embedded Python code

Tags: python, c++, embedding

I'm trying to run a Python code within a C++ application, based of example from this [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html). Everything works fine with just running a script:

```
char filename[] = "D:\\Docs\\Embedding\\bin\\Debug\\load_continiuous_snl_data.py";
FILE* fp;

Py_Initialize();

fp = _Py_fopen(filename, "r");
PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, filename);

Py_Finalize();
```

But when I try to import script as a module, application crashes

```
std::vector<int> ExampleData(5);
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    ExampleData[i] = i+1;
}

PyObject *pName,*pModule,*pFunc,*pname;
PyObject *pValue,*pArgs,*pDict;
Py_Initialize();
pName = PyUnicode_FromString("D:\\Docs\\Embedding\\bin\\Debug\\load_continiuous_snl_data.py");

//pModule = PyImport_Import(pname); //running without this line doesn't lead to crashing

Py_Finalize();
```

I'm using `Python 3.7 32bit on Windows`. Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: You are passing an uninitialised pointer to PyImport_Import. Passing an uninitialised pointer to a C function is **always** an error. You need to read the documentation of PyImport_Import and/or see a couple of examples.

Comment: Also `pName =/= pname`

Comment: `PyImport_Import` imports modules by their module name, for example `load_continiuous_snl_data`. It cannot be used to import a module by its file path. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796925/how-to-import-a-file-by-its-full-path-using-c-api

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped!